# Regex pattern for date format yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: java, regex

I need to validate a date with format `yyyy/MM/dd` using a regex pattern. I already have a regex for the format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

```
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)
```

I'm using the validation from this link http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression. I need the validation for yyyy/MM/dd. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why would you use a regex rather than parsing with `SimpleDateFormat` or something similar? Good luck encoding the leap year rules in a regex. (It may well be possible, but it'll be *horrendous*.)

Comment: `((?:19|20)\\d\\d)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html

Comment: You have `dd/MM/yyyy` and want `yyyy/MM/dd`?! Err, how about simply reordering your current pattern? And I agree with the other comments: better use Java's built-in date-formatter (and parser) functionality.

Comment: I reordered the pattern but I'm using the validation from this link http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-date-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
((?:19|20)\\d\\d)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/([12][0-9]|3[01]|0?[1-9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but as I've just had cause to do this:

```
\d{4}\\\d{2}\\\d{2}
```

Looks a lot neater to my eyes than the other suggestions, and works outside of the 20th/21st century (unclear if OP required this or not).

However, my implementation will match for dates such as 9999/99/99 (clearly invalid) - but as a commenter suggested, `SimpleDateFormat` is the tool for that kind of validation, in my opinion.

If OP were able to use SimpleDateFormat as well as regex, then this would suffice:

```
public static final boolean isDateValid(String date) {
    if (!date.matches("\d{4}\\\d{2}\\\d{2}"))
        return false;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    try {
        sdf.parse(date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseExceptione) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

NB. Usual caveats about SimpleDateFormat not being thread safe etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it:

```
((19|20)[0-9]{2})/((0?[1-9])|1[012])/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(3[01]))
```

Comment: Try it with `19/03/04`. It will accept it, though I guess it should not.

Comment: FYI: this appeared in the low quality posts queue because someone flagged it. Your answer appears plausible, so I presume it is because it is a code-only answer.

Comment: This regex is not working. It won't accept 2014/05/20

Answer (score 0):

i think this helpful for u...

```
var regdate = /^(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex plus a SimpleDateFormat doesn't filter a String date like "2014\26\26", then it would not suffice.

So maybe the best approach is a fully strict regex pattern.

If you turn over your regex (Java) expression from the mkyong website you should be done. As you were already suggested:

```
String pattern = "((?:19|20)\\d\\d)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])";
```

And for extra assurance you can add a SimpleDateFormat. Here is my extra verbose approach:

```
if(stringDate.length()==10 && stringDate.matches("((?:19|20)\\d\\d)/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])")){      
        Date d=null;
        String checkDate=null;
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

        try {
            //Also parses the String as a Date with the format "yyyy/MM/dd"
            //to be sure that the passed string is correct
            d=df.parse(stringDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (d != null) {
            //Transforms the Date into a String with the format "yyyy/MM/dd"
            checkDate=df.format(d);
            System.out.println(checkDate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another simple approach, write a small method that converts the string input to date and convert back the date to string. Then compare both string are equal. If equal then date is correct else its incorrect. All validations are taken care by this approach.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestDate {

    public static boolean isValidDateFormat(String value, String format) {
        Date date = null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            date = sdf.parse(value);
            if (!value.equals(sdf.format(date))) {
                date = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return date != null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String format = "yyyy/MM/dd";
        System.out.println("2017/02/31 isValidDateFormat: " + isValidDateFormat("2017/02/31", format));
        System.out.println("2017/03/31 isValidDateFormat: " + isValidDateFormat("2017/03/31", format));
        System.out.println("2017/04/31 isValidDateFormat: " + isValidDateFormat("2017/04/31", format));
        System.out.println("2017/13/31 isValidDateFormat: " + isValidDateFormat("2017/04/31", format));
        System.out.println("2017/01/35 isValidDateFormat: " + isValidDateFormat("2017/01/35", format));
        System.out.println("017/01/30 isValidDateFormat: " + isValidDateFormat("017/01/30", format));
        // output : 
        //2017/02/31 isValidDateFormat: false
        // 2017/03/31 isValidDateFormat: true
        // 2017/04/31 isValidDateFormat: false
        // 2017/13/31 isValidDateFormat: false
        // 2017/01/35 isValidDateFormat: false
        // 017/01/30 isValidDateFormat: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I wanted to see how the regex Jon Skeet's **very** valid comment mentioned (that a regex handling leap years correctly would be horrendous) would look like. And look - he was right ;)

```
^
(?:(?:19|2[01])\d\d\/(?:1[02]|0[13578])\/(?:[0-2]\d|3[01]))   # 31 day months
|
(?:(?:19|2[01])\d\d\/(?:(?:11|0[469])\/(?:[0-2]\d|30)))       # 30 day months
|
(?:(?:19|2[01])(?:[02468][1235679]|[13579][01345789])|1900|2100)\/02\/(?:[01]\d|2[0-8]) # Non leap year
|
(?:(?:(?:19|21)(?!00)|20)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26]))\/02\/(?:[01]\d|2[0-9]) # Leap year
$
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jplbdb/3).

It tests using four alternations:

- 31 day months
- 30 day months
- February non-leap years
- February leap years

Note that leap years are the years that are a multiple of four. An exception to that rule are multiples of 100 **except** if it's a multiple of 400. (Phew... This is what makes it horrendous.)

Answer (score -1):

It's regexp date format(dd.MM.yyyy). You can adapt this one for you.
`(((0[1-9]{1}|1[0-9]|2[0-9]).(0[1-9]|1[0-2]))|(30.(04|06|09|11))|((30|31).(01|03|05|07|08|10|12))).[0-9]{4}`